# Elementary linear algebra book

Tags: soft-question, online-resources

I read and enjoy Spivak calculus book; I was wondering if there is a similar book (in terms of problems, rigor, etc) for elementary linear algebra?

Comment: Lang; O'Nan; Hoffman and Kunze.

Comment: Take a look at Insel Spence and Friedberg's Linear Algebra.

Comment: @Gerry Yeah... Hoffman (MIT) and Kunze. Although it's written for Math majors, the author considered audiences from other disciplines, as we can read in the Preface.

Answer (score 3):

Some of my favorites are (no ordering ):-

1.Linear Algebra Done Right :- S.Axler

2.Linear Algebra : - Hoffman/Kunze

3.Linear Algebra : A problem Book :- Paul Halmos

4.Linear Algebra - Serge Lang

Answer (score 1):

Try Peter Petersen's Linear Algebra. It's a relatively new book that goes into linear differential equations as an application too.

Answer (score 1):

Do you prefer online/pdf e-books? See this: http://gauravtiwari.org/2011/05/02/free-online-algebra-books/, there are at-least 8 elementary linear algebra books which can interest you.